# How to get slideToggle to slide from the bottom (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

This is kinda hard to explain since english isnt my main language so i think it would be easier if you'd take a look at the site im working on first and then I'll explain what I want to do. Here's the adress: http://ngmat.site90.net/matsedel/ (the site loads slow because the hosting service has implemented a visitor counting service which takes ages to load (doesn't really affect the site itself though).

Anyways, what i want to do is that when you press the "Kamera" button at the bottom I want the 'backgroundCurtain' div to slide up from the top of the bottom bar. It's as simple as that, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I'm quite new to jQuery but what i've read so far is that you need to set "bottom:0;" if you want the div to slide upwards the first time you click it (using slideToggle). So I was thinking of making an invisible div that covers the whole site except the bottom-bar (basically "bottom: 35px") and then setting "bottom: 0" on the backgroundCurtain div. This should make it slide upwards the first time you click it, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the cameraToggle function, set the backgroundCurtain top css property to be as big as the page height and then add this code..

```
$("#camera").on('click', function(){
    $("#backgroundCurtain").animate({top: 'toggle'}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: How do i set it to be as big as the page height?

Comment: `$("#backgroundCurtain").css({'top': $(window).height()});`
Instead window you can use another element..

Comment: Note: I am actually not sliding the element as proper jquery slideToggle does. slideToggle toggles element visibility and height (it would cause into gradually showing content), and this animates its position (i think it looks better)..

Comment: Thanks alot! It's working now after I added/changed some stuff in the code you gave me :), also .animate does indeed look better than .slideToggle.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you don't have to cover all the elements of your site (if I comprehended the point correctly) with that curtain. What you need is to have an independent element for that, with an absolute position and leaving the value of bottom property as 35px. You can find a sample of this kind of functionality in:

http://atomicrobotdesign.com/blog/web-development/configure-jquerys-slidetoggle-to-slide-up-from-the-bottom/

To see the demo;

http://atomicrobotdesign.com/blog_media/toggleslide_multiple.html

Just click on About and Content links